# How to get the Select List ID to compare in JavaScript

Tags: visualforce, javascript

The below code is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Disablefilter(){

   var selectreporttype = document.getElementById('{!$Component.fid:pgBlckId:pgsec:pgsecitem:reportSelList}');
        var selreport = selectreporttype.options[selectreporttype.selectedIndex].value;
       var selectreporttype1 = document.getElementById('{!$Component.fid:pgBlckId:pgsec:pgsecitem:MonthSelList}');   


      if(selreport =='Booked Order YTD')
        {
       //entering into if condition
             document.getElementById('MonthSelList').style.display="block";
        //diable the another selectlist based on one select list.
Entering into the if condition but failing at particular this line

        }
        else{

        document.getElementById('MonthSelList').style.display="none";
         //show the another selectlist based on one select list
        }


  }
```

Comment: you may want to add what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be all "." characters, not ":" characters. Regardless, I'd save myself the hassle and instead get it using a query selector:

```
var selectReportType = document.querySelector("[id$=reportSelList]"), ...
```

Notice also how you sometimes use $Component, and other times you don't. If you do use it, you should be consistent.

Comment: Or even simpler add a style class and select on that. I think it's more efficient but I'm not sure.

Comment: I want to Hide one Complete select list based on another select list value in visual-force page using JavaScript of onchange event.

Comment: @user33763 Again, your code is likely failing because that ID isn't on the page. Make sure you're querying for the object correctly. According to your comments, it fails on the line where you `getElementById('MonthSelList')`, which is *not the correct ID*. Again, I strongly recommend using querySelector instead, or using the full `{!$Component.fid.pgBlckId.pgsec.pgcsecitem.MonthSelList}` construct, but I find that to be cumbersome and not particularly maintainable.

Comment: I tried query selector still not able to hide it.Not sure where i am missing.